# Function to substract 2 dates in sql with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I need a way to substract to dates and get the result in days in sql.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 1):

When both columns you want to subtract are of `date` type, you can just use the **`-`** operator.

Take a look at the [documentation for date functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), in particular table 9-25.

Comment: Please do not post links to outdated versions of postgres. Use `docs/current/static/` instead of `docs/8.1/static/` to link to the current version of postgres manual.

Answer (score -1):

Check here the documentation of PostgreSQl...
[postgresql.org/docs/8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html)

I copied it from this code from this website:

```
age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13')
```

hope it will help you...

Comment: will not work. Check `select extract(day from age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13'));`